# Are Confidential Transactions on Liquid Opt-in?

Tags: liquid

Are confidential transactions on the Liquid network opt-in or mandatory? I know peg transactions reveal the amount and asset ID, but wondering if I can construct vanilla p2pkh outputs with no confidentiality if I want to? I know I can prove these already with binding key but my question is about transaction standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bob:~$ getaddressinfo $ADDR
```

You should see a long value for the “confidential_key” property within the JSON formatted results. It will look something like this:

```
"confidential_key": "030788da8d9ca229cbe57e346daaf8d94cba3ed548b41922a8abefaec91ff1abb1"
```

The confidential_key is the public blinding key, which has been added to the address and is the reason why a confidential address is so long. You will also see that the “getaddressinfo” command shows an associated “unconfidential” address, **which can be used to receive assets if you don’t want to make use of the Confidential Transaction feature for some reason.**

https://docs.blockstream.com/liquid/developer-guide/developer-guide-index.html#confidential-transactions